# ¿Por qué esta función arroja este resultado?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda sobre esta función:

```js
function qwerty(n) {
  return function(y) {
      return y + 1
    }
    (++n) + n
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

El resultado arrojado es 7. ¿Por qué? No lo acabo de entender, se supone que con este sentencia `return function(y).....` devolvería la función ¿No? O sea, todo lo que hay después de return, no debería ser procesado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esto se debe a que con el return no estás devolviendo una función si no el resultado de la llamada a esa función. La manera en la que se están poniendo los espacios es algo raro (seguramente a propósito) y lleva a confusión, que es por lo que el resultado no es el que parecería obvio.

Vamos a descomponer el código poco a poco. Originalmente el código es éste:

```js
function qwerty(n) {
  return function(y) {
      return y + 1
    }
    (++n) + n
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Pero eso es realmente equivalente a esto quitando el salto de línea:

```js
function qwerty(n) {
  return function(y) {
      return y + 1;
    }(++n) + n;
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Eso ya da una idea de por dónde va la cosa. Vamos a mover la definición de la función fuera y a darle un nombre para que no sea tan confusa. Y entonces el código es similar a esto:

```js
function suma1(y) {
  return y + 1;
}

function qwerty(n) {
  return suma1(++n) + n;
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Al hacer (++n) se está sumando 1 a n **antes de llamar a la función**, por lo que es como hacer `suma1(3)` que va a devolver 4, y n ya vale `3` por lo que el resultado es 7 (3+4). Para que sea más claro, esto es *equivalente* al código inicial:

```js
function suma1(y) {
  return y + 1;
}

function qwerty(n) {
  n = n + 1;
  return suma1(n) + n;
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y atención prestada. No había caído en que el paréntesis realizaba la llamada a la función anónima. Gracias.

Answer (score 9):

Esto se conoce como [clausuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript) , y estas declarando una funcion y ejecutandola [(*función anónima*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones#Expresiones_de_funci%C3%B3n) devolviendo el valor de la ejecucion de la funcion anonima mas el valor de n

Primero hagamos un ejemplo de función anónima  y que se ejecute!:

```js
var persona = " H. Díaz"
console.log(
function (nombre) {
  return "Hey " + nombre

}(persona)
)
```

---

Una vez explicado esto; Prestemos atención a tu  código las siguientes lineas:

```
  function(y) {
      return y + 1
    }
    (++n) + n
```

Estas creando una función anónima y ejecutándola al final con los parentesis () pasando por parámetros ++n , esta forma como esta primero se asigna y una vez asignado se ejecuta la función anónima y sumarle el valor de n (que previamente hicistes ++n)

Ejecutemos el mismo código en el snippet cambiando n =  2

```js
console.log(
  function(y) {
    return y + 1
  }(2 + 2) + 2
)
```

pero que tal si cambiamos el codigo para que se vea un poco mejor , el codigo que tienes es equivalente a :

```js
function qwerty(n) {
  function incremento(y){
    return y + 1
  }
  n = n + 1;
  return (incremento(n) + n)
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Incluso se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
function qwerty(n) {
   n = n + 1;
  return function (){
    return n + n + 1
  }()
 
}

console.log(qwerty(2));
```

Te recomiendo leer esta pregunta es relacionada:

> [¿Qué sentido tiene un "()" al final de la definición de una función en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173839/qu%c3%a9-sentido-tiene-un-al-final-de-la-definici%c3%b3n-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-javascrip)

<sub>El amigo que te dio ese código para empezar JavaScript... no es tu amigo</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Buena explicación fácil de entender.

Answer (score 7):

Para comprender cómo funciona, debemos dividir el bloque de la siguiente forma, de adentro hacia afuera:

```
function(y) {
  return y + 1
}
```

Es la declaración de una función anónima, que se debe ejecutar inmediatamente después de ser declarada. La forma de ejecutar una función anónima, es pasar los parámetros entre paréntesis:

```
function(y) {
    return y + 1
}(1)
```

Por ejemplo, la llamada anterior devolverá `2`.

Luego, estamos usando como parámetro el valor ++n, que es un incremento a la variable n antes de usarla. Es decir, se lee `suma 1 a n, y envíala como parámetro`. Con esto, el valor de entrada para la función anónima es 3 cuando el parámetro n es 2.

```
function(y) {
    return y + 1
}(++n) // n = 2
```

Por último, estamos sumando el valor de n al resultado de la función anónima, que, ya que sumamos 1 a su valor a través del operador incremental, ahora su valor es 3. Dado que el resultado de la función es 4, `4 + 3 = 7`.

```
function querty(n) { // n = 2
    return function(y) {
        return y + 1 
    }(++n) + n // ++n = 3
    // function(y){...}(3) = 4
    // n = 3
    // 4 + 3 = 7
}
```

Comment: Gracias, nada como una buena explicación para poder entender las cosas. Está todo entendido! Gracias.